# React Dev tools show my Component as Unknown

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following simple component:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css.scss'

export default (props) => {
  let activeClass = props.out ? 'is-active' : ''
  return (
    <div className='hamburgerWrapper'>
      <button className={'hamburger hamburger--htla ' + activeClass}>
        <span />
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I look for it in the react dev tools, I see:

[image]

Is this because I need to extend React component? Do I need to create this as a variable and do so?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This happens when you export an anonymous function as your component. If you name the function (component) and then export it, it will show up in the React Dev Tools properly.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {}
export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it bad practice to leave it unnamed for the simple "dumb" state-less components?

Comment: My preference is to name, then export in different lines due to this problem. However I'd hesitate calling it a bad practice.

Comment: This same thing affects javascript backtraces as well, for example in the Chrome dev tools.  Anonymous functions will be labeled generically and this can make it hard to interpret backtraces.

Comment: As a person who has inherited an entire app of anonymous functions that show as '<Unknown>' in react dev tools, I highly recommend you name all your components for your own sanity. See https://medium.com/@stevemao/do-not-use-anonymous-functions-to-construct-react-functional-components-c5408ec8f4c7

Comment: @program247365 Yes, thank you for saying this. I too inherited this mess of an app... hundreds of 'Unknown' components... thanks prior dev team!

Comment: You can use `export default function MyComponent` as well

Comment: I am still having issues with all my components showing up as anoymous. I check every one and still show up as anoymous in Firefox tools.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 19):

I realise the original question has been correctly answered already, but I just wanted to note a very similar issue you may encounter if using React.memo() or similar function. Consider the following code:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(props => <div>Hello</div>)
export default MyComponent
```

The component will still display as `Anonymous` in devtools and certain React error messages (e.g. prop-types validation).

Ensuring that the Component is defined before trying to memoise it resolves this issue, e.g:

```
const MyComponent = props => <div>Hello</div>
export default React.memo(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 10):

To add to Michael Jaspers answer, if you want to use a named import (instead of default export), you can do like so:

```
const MyComponent = props => <div />
export { MyComponent }
```

The component will show in React DevTools with the correct name.

**Note:** If you had exported the expression directly:

```
export const MyComponent = props => <div />
```

This would then show as `Anonymous` or `Unknown` in React DevTools